# Getting rid of Back/Forward buttons in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, magellan

I have managed to run magellan's (a library which helps with navigation between pages) [hello world project](https://code.google.com/p/magellan-framework/wiki/GettingStarted) so far. The problem is that I don't know how to get rid of the back/forward buttons - those in the picture:

[image]

I think they are there by default there, regardless of the library.

For the library to work, I got to insert this line in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Frame x:Name="MainFrame" />
```

Is there a way to make the buttons go away?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
<Frame x:Name="MainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
```